# Oracle CONNECT Operations

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I've read through the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm) concerning the `CONNECT` operations, but I can't seem to get my head around a database query we have in an existing application. Below is a simplified version of the query.

```
SELECT LEVEL,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT MY_MONTH MY_LABEL,
       b.*
FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS ORDERING, 
           MY_AREA,
           TRUNC (THE_MONTH, 'MONTH') AS MY_MONTH
    FROM MY_TABLE
    ORDER BY MY_AREA, MY_MONTH DESC
) b
WHERE LEVEL <= 3
START WITH 1 = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR MY_AREA = MY_AREA
       AND PRIOR ORDERING = ORDERING - 1
       AND PRIOR MY_MONTH <= ADD_MONTHS(MY_MONTH, 6);
```

While I have a basic understanding of the `CONNECT` functionalities, this combination has me lost. Can anyone explain what is going on in this query?

I think the end says to get all of the rows that have the same area and a row number 1 less than the current row number and a date before 6 months in the future from the current date. I would guess this would only return 1 row (due to the row number criteria) or 0 rows if the other criteria weren't met. And then maybe the first `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` says to get that row's `MY_MONTH` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `b`, which is a table of `MY_AREA` (a number?), `MY_MONTH`, which is a month-truncated date (i.e. the days are all set to `01`), and an aliased `ROWNUM`, which is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause, which is `ORDER BY MY_AREA, MY_MONTH DESC`, e.g.:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+
| ORDERING | MY_AREA | MY_MONTH  |
+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1        | 10      | 01-SEP-12 |
| 2        | 10      | 01-JAN-12 |
| 3        | 12      | 01-AUG-12 |
| 4        | 12      | 01-JUN-12 |
| 5        | 12      | 01-MAY-12 |
| 6        | 12      | 01-JAN-12 |
| 7        | 12      | 01-JAN-10 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
```

The `WHERE` clause doesn't come into play until later, so move on to `START WITH`, which says only `1 = 1`. This means that every row in `b` will be used in the query; if you had had another condition here, e.g. `my_area < 5` or whatever, only a certain set of rows would have been used.

Now, the `CONNECT BY`, which determines how the hierarchy should be built. This works like a `WHERE` clause, except for the special `PRIOR` keyword which tells the DB to look at the previous level in the hierarchy. So:

- `PRIOR MY_AREA = MY_AREA` just means that the child node has to have the same value for `MY_AREA'
- `PRIOR ORDERING = ORDERING - 1` means that the child should come *one row after* the current node in `b`'s ordering.
- `PRIOR MY_MONTH <= ADD_MONTHS(MY_MONTH, 6)` means that in order to be joined into the hierarchy, the previous `MY_MONTH` should be 6 months or less after the date of the current node.

The whole hierarchy is then created. `LEVEL` (special for `CONNECT BY`...) is set to the level in the hierarchy, `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` gives the `MY_MONTH` value for the root of that hierarchy and aliases it to `MY_LABEL`. After this, the table would look something like the following table. I've added separators for each hierarchy for clarity.

```
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| LEVEL | MY_LABEL  | ORDERING | MY_AREA | MY_MONTH  |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-SEP-12 | 1        | 10      | 01-SEP-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-JAN-12 | 2        | 10      | 01-JAN-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-AUG-12 | 3        | 12      | 01-AUG-12 |
| 2     | 01-AUG-12 | 4        | 12      | 01-JUN-12 |
| 3     | 01-AUG-12 | 5        | 12      | 01-MAY-12 |
| 4     | 01-AUG-12 | 6        | 12      | 01-JAN-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-JUN-12 | 4        | 12      | 01-JUN-12 |
| 2     | 01-JUN-12 | 5        | 12      | 01-MAY-12 |
| 3     | 01-JUN-12 | 6        | 12      | 01-JAN-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-MAY-12 | 5        | 12      | 01-MAY-12 |
| 2     | 01-MAY-12 | 6        | 12      | 01-JAN-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-JAN-12 | 6        | 12      | 01-JAN-12 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 01-JAN-10 | 7        | 12      | 01-JAN-10 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

So, as you can see, each of the rows appears at the top of its own hierarchy, with all nodes meeting the `CONNECT BY` criteria under it.

Finally, the `WHERE` clause is applied; this chops off all of the levels `> 3` in every hierarchy, so you're left with a maximum of 3 levels. This affects only one row in the middle hierarchy, the one with `LEVEL` = 4.

Comment: How is there ever more than 2 levels if the child has to be 1 row before the parent? Also, you might want to reorder your table (first ordering is asc). And area is a string.

Comment: I am still lost on the ordering criteria. Like in section 3 of your table, the "1" ordering row is included for the "3" ordering root. How does this satisfy `PRIOR ORDERING = ORDERING - 1`?

Comment: Oh. Maybe the "PRIOR" refers to the root OR the last child (i.e. whatever the last row was)?

Comment: Hrm. There is also still something amiss. My first "section" of the results has 3 levels.

Comment: All of the rows are included with `START WITH 1 = 1`; that is to say that all of the rows become a root for their own tree.

Comment: The 1st level, the root, is determined by `START WITH` while the 2nd (and greater) levels are determined by the `CONNECT BY .. PRIOR` clause; at the 2nd level `PRIOR` refers to the root. At the 3rd level, it refers to the 2nd level, and so on. Also, I corrected the sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I worked it out. I was confused about what rows the `PRIOR` statements referred to. One thing the answer seems to miss is that the sections usually have 3 entries. Because the `AND PRIOR ORDERING = ORDERING - 1` means that the child has an ordering 1 MORE than the previous row. If you fix this, I will mark the answer as correct. The date might be similarly backwards. The `PRIOR` is on the left of the equality, so that refers to the earlier row.

Comment: Woops, you're correct about the `ORDERING` bit, fixed in the answer now. I address the "3 entries" bit in the last paragraph about the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ok. Only thing I see is that the 1st section should actually only have 1 level (just realized the dates are more than 6 months apart).

Comment: Yep, fixed. This is what happens when a human makes the tables instead of a computer :(